# Error cannot convert 'std::string* {aka std::basic_string<char>*}' to 'node*' in assignment

Tags: c++, arrays, linked-list

So I have a linked list of 3 books already. Now I want to add the donated books to the previous linked list. (`donation` is an array of string (book titles) and `amount` is the number of books donated). Here's my code:

```
void newbrowse(int amount, string donation[])
{
    head= new node;
    second=new node;
    tail= new node;

    head->bookname = "Book1";
    head->next = second;

    second->bookname = "Book2";
    second->next = tail;

    tail->bookname = "Book3";
    for (int i=0; i<amount; i+=1)
    {
        tail->next = &donation[i];
        tail = donation[i];
    }

    display = head;
    cout<<"Total books:"<<endl;
    for (int j=1; j<=(amount+3); j+=1)
    {
        cout<<display->bookname<<endl;
        display = display->next;
    }
}
```

I got that error on this line `tail->next = &donation[i];`. From what I understand, that line meant that `tail->next` is now pointing to the address of `donation[i]`, so I don't know why I'm getting an error? `tail->next` is a pointer so I put ampersand on the donation.

What is this error and how do I fix this?

Comment: The error could not be more clear: you're trying to assign a `string*` into a `node*`. Did you mean to point `tail` to a `new node` instead? (where the new node's `bookname` is `donation[i]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with the comments above, nodes are not strings, and you can't assign one to the other even when pointers are involved. I'm guessing that you meant something like this

```
for (int i=0; i<amount; i+=1)
{
    node* n = new node;
    n->bookname = donation[i];
    tail->next = n;
    tail = n;
}
```

You did this (more or less) correctly in the first half of your function. You only have to do the same here.

Comment: should I not make `n->next = NULL`?

Comment: @Novalcia Yes, probably. Since I can't see your definiton of `node` I can't know all the details of what you need to do.